# change website URL on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I published my website locally on IIS  like this: 10.22.16.255:1113 and it's working great, but i need the same website work on 10.22.16.255:1113/tc (adding "/tc" to same IP), is there any way to make it happen ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can add virtual directories: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx

To create a virtual directory by using IIS Manager
In IIS Manager, expand the local computer and the Sites folder, and then find the Web site that you want to add a virtual directory for. Use the following steps:
For , right-click the site or folder where you want to create the virtual directory, and then click Add Virtual Directory.
For Windows Server 2008, right-click the site or folder where you want to create the virtual directory, click Manage Web Site, and then click Add Virtual Directory.
In the Add Virtual Directory dialog box, specify the following information:
Alias. Type a name for the virtual directory. Choose a short name that is easy to type, because the user types this name to access the Web site.
Physical Path. Type or browse to the physical directory that contains the virtual directory. You can select an existing folder or create a new one to contain the content for the virtual directory.
To provide credentials to connect to a UNC path, click the Connect as button.
Click OK.

Comment: I tried that before but it gave me : 
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 



Line 19:     <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="ar-EG" />
Line 20:     <customErrors mode="Off" />
Line 21:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 22:       <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
Line 23:     </authentication>

Comment: http://forums.iis.net/t/1148147.aspx?It+is+an+error+to+use+a+section+registered+as+allowDefinition+MachineToApplication+beyond+application+level+